# Symfony2, forms, username_parameter and firewall parameters

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm using a custom authenticator that implements [SimpleFormAuthenticationInterface](https://github.com/symfony/Security/blob/master/Core/Authentication/SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface.php).

However, because of the way forms have their input `name="form[username]"` I'm not able to pass that to the `username_parameter` and into `createToken`. Is there a way to do this or will I have to write my own [Authentication Listener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/SimpleFormAuthenticationListener.php)?

Here's my config:

```
firewalls:
  secured_area:
        provider: UserRepository
        pattern: ^/user
          simple_form:
             username_parameter:
             password_parameter:
             authenticator: UserAuthenticator
             login_path:  /login
             check_path:  /user/auth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `Request`'s `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag` resolves parameters that are of html array form in the security.yml configuration

Under:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php#L103-L150

So you can use and do something like:

```
firewalls:
  secured_area:
        provider: UserRepository
        pattern: ^/user
          simple_form:
             username_parameter: MyForm[username]
             password_parameter: MyForm[password]
             authenticator: UserAuthenticator
             login_path:  /login
             check_path:  /user/auth
```